# Ionic tabs, how to show spinner on tab change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm really new to `ionic v.1`. What I want to do is that, everytime that the tab, changes it will show a spinner for 1second. I don't know what to do. But in `angularjs v.1.6.x` the codes like this:

**Index.html in plain angularjs v.1.6.x**

```
<div ng-view ng-show="statechange"></div>

<!-- show loader after statechange -->
<div ng-show="!statechange" wp-resolve>
     <div id="_loader_"><i class="fa fa-spin fa-circle-o-notch fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</div>
```

**angularjs code**

```
app.directive('wpResolve', function($rootScope){
return{
    link: function(scope, element){
        $rootScope.statechange = true;
        var unregister = $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(){
            $rootScope.statechange = false;
        });
        scope.$on('$destroy', unregister);
    }
   };
});

//in my app.config()

$routeProvider
.when('/',{
    templateUrl: '_routes/home',
    controller: 'homectrl',
    resolve: {
        delay: function($q, $timeout){
            var delay = $q.defer();
            $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
            return delay.promise;
        }
    }
}); ...
```

That's the plain angularjs v.1.6.x code! But in ionic, it uses the angularjs v.1.5.3. And here's the code for tab change:

```
 .state('tab', {
url: '/tab',
abstract: true,
templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'

  });
```

Thanks! What I want to do is the same as angularjs v.1.6.x code! Like displaying a spinner every tab change. How to do it?

Comment: create a factory and use that in your directive

Comment: Can you provide me a code sir? I really don't know. @SaurabhAgrawal